# SCSS, преобразованный в массив, нужно правильно перебрать и создать вложенные массивы

Tags: javascript, массивы, scss

Допустим есть такой массив:
`let arr = ['asad{','font-size:12px', 'qwe{', 'asd{','}','}','}']`
на выходе нужно , чтоб получилось:

```
[
    [
      'asad{',
      'font-size:12px', 
      [
       'qwe{', 
       ['asd{','}'],
       '}'
      ],
     '}'
    ]
]
```

Comment: На выходе SCSS отдаёт CSS – там нет никаких массивов.

Comment: @Vadizar Я считываю activeTextEditor(код) с vscode  и получаю весь код в одной строке, затем делаю split('\n') и получается одномерный массив. Мне же нужно чтобы вложеные блоки тоже являлись массивами.

Comment: Ради интереса, можно узнать, зачем вы вернули опечатки в заголовок? В коллективном исправлении отпечаток нет ничего обидного или агрессивного, все могут опечататься. Опечатки мешают будущему поиску ответов на похожие вопросы и отнимают лишнее время у читающих на восстановление смысла. Или вы не считаете, что с заголовком что-то не так?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty строка УЖЕ преобразована в массив , по-этому "преобразованиЕ " не подходит

Comment: Хорошо, простите, но не лучше ли было тогда исправить по-другому? Сейчас у вас несколько несогласованных слов и смысл поэтому теряется. Вы имели в виду "Преобразованный в массив SCSS нужно правильно перебрать и создать вложенные массивы"?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty да, всё верно! Если хотите - можете поправить(ну, это если вам нужно для ачивки)

Comment: Мне не для ачивки, мне это ничего не даст) Просто постарайтесь стать на место других: некоторые читают сайт регулярно и пытаются отвечать, это много вопросов в день, и очень утомляет продираться через десятки неперечитанных заголовков, с опечатками и без пунктуации, это отнимает время и силы, которые можно тратить на ответы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так подойдёт?

```js
const arr = ['asad{', 'font-size:12px', 'qwe{', 'asd{', '}', '}', '}'];

const result = fillLevel(arr, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, '  '));

function fillLevel(source, destination) {
  while (source.length) {
    const chunk = source.shift();

    if (chunk.includes('{')) {
      destination.push(fillLevel(source, [chunk]))
    } else {
      destination.push(chunk);
      if (chunk.includes('}')) return destination;
    }
  }

  return destination;
}
```